# Node/Multer Get Filename

Tags: node.js, multer

I am using the following to upload files to a directory via Multer. It works great, but I need to perform some actions after upload that require the name of the file I just posted to the "upload" directory. How do I get the name of the file I just posted?

```
// Multer storage options
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'upload/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now() + '.pdf');
  }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/multer', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  // Need full filename created here
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209875/should-not-allow-file-upload-if-anyone-changes-extension-from-exe-to-png-via-mul

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var multer=require("multer");
var upload=multer({dest:"uploads/"});
app.post("/multer", upload.single("file"), function(req,res){
    console.log(req.file.filename);
});
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. User wants to get generated filename not the originalname. Thank you!

Answer (score 36):

`request.file` gives the following stats, from which you would just need to pick `request.file.originalname` or `request.file.filename` to get the new filename created by nodejs app.

```
{ 
  fieldname: 'songUpload',
  originalname: '04. Stairway To Heaven - Led Zeppelin.mp3',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'audio/mp3',
  destination: './uploads',
  filename: 'songUpload-1476677312011',
  path: 'uploads/songUpload-1476677312011',
  size: 14058414 
}
```

Eg, in nodejs express mvc app with ecma-6,

```
var Express = require('express');
var app = Express();

var multipartUpload = Multer({storage: Multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) { callback(null, './uploads');},
    filename: function (req, file, callback) { callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());}})
}).single('songUpload');

app.post('/artists', multipartUpload, (req, resp) => {
     val originalFileName = req.file.originalname
     console.log(originalFileName)
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209875/should-not-allow-file-upload-if-anyone-changes-extension-from-exe-to-png-via-mul

Answer (score 13):

Accessing uploaded files data differs in Multer, depending whether you are uploading **single** or **multiple** files. Access data like so:

*uploading single file:*

```
req.file
```

*uploading multiple files:*

```
req.files
```

Comment: It's `req.files` for `multer.any()`. Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer on github, you have access to it in
`res.req.file.filename`
See there for more informations https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/302

Answer (score 2):

```
    app.post('/multer', upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
  // Need full filename created here
const file = req.file
if (!file) {
    const error = new Error('Please upload a file')
    error.httpStatusCode = 400
    return next(error)
  }
 res.send(file) #Here
});
```

You need recover file from this line

```
 res.send(file)
```

using file.filename
This output sample

```json
{
  "fieldname": "myFile",
  "originalname": "isc te esta esperando.jpg",
  "encoding": "7bit",
  "mimetype": "image/jpeg",
  "destination": "uploads",
  "filename": "myFile-1602293858948.eaf",
  "path": "uploads/myFile-1602293858948.eaf",
  "size": 297720
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using 
request.file.filename

fieldname   Field name specified in the form
originalname    Name of the file on the user's computer 
encoding    Encoding type of the file
mimetype    Mime type of the file
size    Size of the file in bytes