# Should not allow file upload if anyone changes extension from exe to png via multer in node js application

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I'm uploading file using `multer` in my nodejs (express js) application which is working fine. I have put a mime type check there also to allow only png files but if I change the ext of the uploaded file from `abc.exe` to `abc.png` it also gets uploaded which is wrong.

here is my code.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var imagefolder = __base + 'public/complaintimages/';

var diskstorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (common.ImageMimeTypes.indexOf(file.mimetype) < 0) {
            common.ActionOutput.Status = common.ActionStatus.WrongFileUploaded;
            common.ActionOutput.Message = 'Invalid image file: ' + file.originalname;
            cb(new Error('FileUpload:' + common.ActionStatus.WrongFileUploaded), null);
        } else
            cb(null, imagefolder);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var filenm = randomstring.generate(10);
        //console.log(filenm + file.originalname);
        cb(null, filenm + file.originalname);
    }
});
var upload = multer({
    storage: diskstorage
});
```

It should check the file content for mime type. Renaming other into png should not be uploaded. It seems to be bug in the library.
Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your route handler when you have the saved file name, you can use the [`mmmagic`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mmmagic) module:

```
var mmm = require('mmmagic'),
var magic = new mmm.Magic(mmm.MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);
magic.detectFile(fileName, function (err, mime) {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // check the mime
    // and remove the file if you don't like it
    // plus send a correct response to the client
  }
});
```

### Update

If `mmmagic` doesn't work for you then you can use the `file-type` module but it works on buffers so you first will have to read the file (or some part of it) into a buffer and check the mime type with `file-type`. The `read-chunk` module can be handy to read part of the file.

See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-chunk

Comment: i tried installing this in my windows machine but it's giving some error.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi See my updated answer for other options.

Comment: I already tried this but it does not support all mime types like doc, html etc

Comment: @JitendraPancholi You add more more file types [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type/blob/master/index.js). It's an open source project.

Comment: great, but what should i add for doc file?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures and http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me.