# accessing properties from javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, backend, multer

I have below object.

```
export const multerOptions = {
    storage: diskStorage({
        destination: multerConfig.dest,
        filename: (_req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
            /* istanbul ignore next */
            cb(null, `${uuid()}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
        },
    }),
};
```

when I am printing multerOptions.storage it is returning below.

```
   diskStorage({
        destination: multerConfig.dest,
        filename: (_req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
            /* istanbul ignore next */
            cb(null, `${uuid()}${extname(file.originalname)}`);
        },
    }),
.
```

is there anyway I can access this `filename` or `destination`

Comment: Are you emitting this muter object in API endpoint?

Comment: yes..actually I need to mock using jest..not able to do

Comment: Do you want the uploaded file name to be accessed? Please check 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328846/node-multer-get-filename

Comment: `req.file.filename` in the route you are handling the image upload.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is for single file upload

```
 /**
 * Module for geting image from s3 cloud server
 */
exports.upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: function (req, file, cb) {
            const path = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME;
            cb(null, path || 'uploads/');
        },
        acl: 'authenticated-read',
        // acl: 'public-read',
        key: function (req, file, cb) {

            console.log("file========", req);
            // console.log(req.path.split('/')[1]);
            // console.log(path.parse(file.originalname).name.replace(" ", "-"));
            // console.log(Date.now() + path.parse(file.originalname).ext);
            // req.path.split('/')[1] ===== Sub-Folder
            // path.parse(file.originalname).name.replace(" ", "-") + Date.now() + path.parse(file.originalname).ext ===== File name
            cb(null, req.path.split('/')[1]+'/'+path.parse(file.originalname).name.replace(" ", "-") + Date.now() + path.parse(file.originalname).ext);
        }
    })
}).single('file');
```

For Multiple file upload

```
/**
 * Module for geting image from s3 cloud server
 */
 exports.uploadmultiple = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: function (req, file, cb) {
            const path = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME;
            cb(null, path || 'uploads/');
        },
        acl: 'authenticated-read',
        // acl: 'public-read',
        key: function (req, file, cb) {

            console.log(req.path.split('/')[1]);
            console.log(path.parse(file.originalname).name.replace(" ", "-"));
            console.log(Date.now() + path.parse(file.originalname).ext);
            // req.path.split('/')[1] ===== Sub-Folder
            // path.parse(file.originalname).name.replace(" ", "-") + Date.now() + path.parse(file.originalname).ext ===== File name
            cb(null, req.path.split('/')[1]+'/'+path.parse(file.originalname).name.replace(" ", "-") + Date.now() + path.parse(file.originalname).ext);
        }
    })
}).array('files', 2);
```

You can get more info over [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3)